# Scientist assembles a robot which is a duplicate of himself

Tags: identify-this-movie

I don't remember much apart from that. A scientist, not good at human relations, makes a robot that is his exact duplicate with the plan of sending it into space for a long trip. The robot through the course of the movie learns about humans, their customs and culture, while the scientist always remains reserved. In the end, the robot falls in love with a girl, and doesn't want to leave, so the scientist, not telling anyone, goes in his place.

The color orange was their uniform color, if memory serves (it's quite possible that it doesn't). The movie was of the older variety, pre 90's definitely, quite possible pre 80's.

Does this remind anyone of any movie?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like [Making Mr. Right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Making_Mr._Right) (1987) to me. Repressed scientist, deep space project, robot that falls in love with a woman, it's all there.

Comment: That's the one! :)